# Google Script : authorization / permission errors on a script RUN MANUALLY inside of the Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

I have tried multiple file ids, with and without the full URL. I am not given a dialog box about permissions.

Comment: Is the file you are trying to open in your drive?  If you open a file in the browser, the URL ending is like this:  `key=847rifhdi987rhoifdjfuhfooerg76tr7tfgiu9re7deykE#gid=0`  You need the part after the equal sign, and before the pound (hash tag) sign.  Or it could look like this:  `/d/1nBSqv7iuurjf87gioiehDVDzCPiB-AA9KLFHIHHt3/edit?usp=drive_web`  Where you need everything after `/d/` and before `/edit?`  Make sure you get the dash and the numbers after the dash.

Comment: I've tried multiple file id's...  with a file ID being something like this: 1ABty8ZiTqZ8MHPkFipjL8wDZqR2Ae9PLrNAQtW2QD2k

Comment: We need a way to re-create the error message.  What type of file are you trying to open?  Is it your file?  Is it someone else's file?  Is it a shared file owned by someone else?  Without knowing that information, there is no way anyone can answer your question.

Comment: Hi Sandy, the file is mine, it's owned by me.

I recreated it and I'm getting the same message.

Apparently accessing files in google scripts is a pain in the ass! I'm having a similar but different problem while trying to do the exact same thing in SpreadSheetApp 
here's the link to my question:
[cannot call, null, cannot find file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459805/google-scripts-accessing-spreadsheet-files-typeerror-cannot-call-method-open)