# Google Scripts: accessing spreadsheet files, TypeError: Cannot call method "openById" of null. (line 2, file "Code") Dismiss

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

The code:

```
function myFunction() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().openById('https://docs.google.com/a/e4b.us/spreadsheets/d/1DBty8ZiTqZ8MHPkFipjL8wDZqR2Ae9PLrNAQtW2QD2k/edit#gid=0');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var mylocationInfo   = ss.getRange("A2:B4").getValues();
logger.log(mylocationInfo.getData)
```

}

I thought that maybe removing non-essential aspects of the url, like the /edit#gid=0, would help. It didn't.

Here's evidence that the URL is indeed valid:
[image: Here's evidence that the URL is indeed valid:]

*EDIT* I've tried it without the entire URL, just using the actual ID and I receive the same message.

*EDIT* I removed the function ".getActiveSpreadSheet" and get the error "Bad Value" 
I tried changing getById to getByUrl, inputing the full URL, and i get the error message that the file with the ID is missing. As was shown by the screenshot, the file exists. The url was copy-pasted immediately before executing the script.
changed:3:07pm

*EDIT* I tried linking to a different spreadsheet using getByUrl and got the same error message. Changed 3:10pm

Why does getById return Null?
Why can't getByUrl find my files?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with DriveApp [here is my stack overflow question entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369893/google-script-authorization-permission-errors-on-a-script-run-manually-insid?noredirect=1#comment45161964_28369893)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using: `getActiveSpreadsheet()` and `openById()` at the same time.  That's a conflict.  You need to use one or the other.

Your code:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .openById('https://docs.google.com/a/e4b.us/spreadsheets/d/Your ID/edit#gid=0');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

Plus you aren't using the ID, you are using the URL.  If you want to get a reference to the file by URL, use the method:  `openByUrl()`

The code should look like this:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Your ID');
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
```

The variable name `ss` stands for **s**pread **s**heet.  That's the entire spreadsheet file.  `sheet` is one sheet tab inside the spreadsheet.

Comment: As I tried to explain in the edits, I figured out the conflict you just mentioned so I removed .getActiveSheets, but it still doesn't work.

I input your code and it tells me the file is missing, but, as is shownfrom the screenshot, the id does indeed exist. 

I get the same error when I use openByUrl, together with the url instead of the Id

Comment: I don't know where to go from here.  When I have a problem that I can't figure out, I start over from the beginning, and make sure every step is working.  Create a new file, with just a little data in it, and see if you can get some code to work on that.  Use debug to step through every single line of code, to see what line is giving the error.  If there was a problem on Google's end with `openByUrl()`, then there would be thousands of people complaining that it wasn't working.

Comment: well considering that there is one line of code, it's hard to go wrong. I'll try creating a fresh file. I'm thinking it may have something to do with permissions inside of google drive or their file system. I tried logging a bug report on the relevant code.google page, but the submit report button is greyed out and inactive! There's no feedback as to why it's inactive, either. I'll probably just migrate everything to another system, if I would have done that from the start it probably would've cost me less time than trying to solve this single issue. I'll try that last bit of advice, thanks!

Comment: update: created a new file, ran it through the the same one line, one function script and it gave me the same error.

Comment: I just ran the following line of code:  `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/MySpreadsheet_ID/edit#gid=1676698598');` and it worked.

Comment: Here's your code : [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/FezQXqa.png) ---------
Here's mine : [imgur](http://i.imgur.com/u89UXAc.png)

Same problem

Comment: For the sake of posting here on Stack Overflow, I removed my actual ID.  So that's going to give an error.  I just tried it again with a different spreadsheet, and got mine to work.  `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/MyID/edit#gid=0');`  I don't know what to tell you.